# Asymptotic Moments of the Binomial Distribution, $E(X/(np))^k = 1 + O(k^2/n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$ be the sum of $n$ Bernoulli($p$) random variables.

What is the value of $E(X/(np))^k$, where $k$ is a large integer, as $n$ grows large?

From calculations the first values are

```
E1        = 1
E(X/np)   = 1
E(X/np)^2 = 1 + r/n
E(X/np)^3 = 1 + 3r/n + ((-1+p)(-1+2p))/(np)^2
E(X/np)^4 = 1 + 6r/n + O[1/n]^2
E(X/np)^5 = 1 + 10r/n + O[1/n]^2
E(X/np)^6 = 1 + 15r/n + O[1/n]^2
E(X/np)^7 = 1 + 21r/n + O[1/n]^2
...
```

where $r = (1-p)/p$

So my guess would be that one could obtain a result like $E(X/(np))^k = 1 + O(k^2/n)$, but I'm not sure how I'd proceed.

For sums of $\{+1, -1\}$ random variables, I'm aware that we can bound the moments by replacing each one with a normal random variable with the same variance. However converting this result to the non central case doesn't seem obvious?

Comment: By $E(X/(np))^k$, do you mean $E[(X/(np))^k]$ or $(E[X/(np)])^k$?

Comment: The former. I take expectation to bind less strongly, not to have too many brackets.

Comment: By the CLT, $X=np+\sqrt{np(1-p)}Z_n$ where $E(Z_n)=0$ and $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution, with $Z$ standard normal, hence $X/(np)=1+\sigma Z_n/\sqrt{n}$ with $\sigma^2=(1-p)/p$ and one expects that $$E((X/(np))^k)=E(1+k\sigma Z_n/\sqrt{n}+k(k-1)\sigma^2Z_n^2/n)+o(1/n)=1+k(k-1)\sigma^2E(Z^2)/n+o(1/n),$$ that is, $$\lim n\cdot(E((X/(np))^k)-1)=k(k-1)\sigma^2/2= k(k-1)r/2.$$

Comment: @Did Can we make this nonasymptotic somehow? Perhaps by using a qualitative version of CLT, which says something about how fast $Z_n$ converges to $Z$?

Comment: Berry-Esseen then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

Comment: @Did I suppose something like the Variant Berry–Esseen Theorem would work ( https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=2213 ) but then I'm still left with estimating non-central Gaussian moments, and I don't know the asymptotics of those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right universal bound is
$$E\left[\left(\frac{X}{np}\right)^k\right] \le \left(1+\frac{k}{2np}\right)^k.$$
For $k = O(\sqrt{np})$ this explains the $1+O(k^2/(np))$ behaviour.

I wrote a note detailing the answer here https://thomasahle.com/#paper-bi-moments .

**Using the Moment Generating Function**

Let $$m(t) = E[e^{t X}] = (1-p+pe^t)^n \le \exp(\mu(e^t-1)),$$ where $\mu=np$.
This last bound is the moment generation of a Poisson random variable, so the following bound will hold in that case as well.

Now $E[X^k] \le m(t)t^{-k}k!$ follows easily from the expansion $E[e^{tX}]=\sum_i E[X^i]t^i/i!$.
However, we will need the slightly stronger bound:
$$E[X^k] \le m(t)(k/(et))^k.$$
This follows from the basic inequality $1+x\le e^x$, where we substitute $tx/k-1$ for $x$ to get $tx/k \le e^{tx/k-1} \implies x^k \le e^{tx}(k/(et))^k$. Taking expectations we get the intended bound.

We define $B=k/\mu$ like above, and take $t$ such that $t e^t=B$.
(This $t$ is also known as $W(B)$, using the Lambert function.)

We then have
$$\begin{align}
E[(X/\mu)^k]
&\le
m(t)(\mu t)^{-k}(k/e)^k
\\&\le 
\exp(\mu(e^t-1))\big(\frac{k}{e\mu t}\big)^k
\\&=
\exp(\mu(B/t-1)+tk-k)
\\&= \exp(k f(B))
,
\end{align}$$
where $f(B) = 1/t+t-1-1/B$.
We can bound $\exp(f(x))$ by $B/\log(B+1) \le 1+B/2 \le e^{B/2}$ using standard bounds on the Lambert function.

This finally gives the bounds
$$
\|X/\mu\|_k \le \frac{B}{\log(B+1)} \le e^{B/2}.
$$
Taking $k$ powers this means
$$
\text{and}\quad E[(X/\mu)^k] \le \exp(k^2/(2np)),
$$
where $e^{k^2/(2np)} = 1+O(k^2/(np))$ when $k = O(\sqrt{np})$.

**Old attempt using norms:**

I found the following interesting non-asymptotic bound:

Let $\|X\|_k = E[|X|^k]^{1/k}$ and use the triangle inequality
$$\|X\|_k \le np + \|X-np\|_k.$$

To bound the second term, we use Latala's formula for sums of iid. random variables:
$$\|X\|_k = \|\sum_i X_i - E[X_i]\|_k \lesssim \inf_{\max\{2,\frac kn\}\le s\le k} \frac ks \left(\frac nk\right)^{1/s} \|X_i - E[X_i]\|_s$$

For  Bernoulli random variables with probability $p$: $\|B-p\|_k = \left(p (1-p)^k+(1-p) p^k\right)^{1/k} \le p^{1/k}$.

Let $\beta = \frac{k}{np}$.
We assume $k\le n$ and $np\ge 1$.
Optimizing in Latala's we have

$$
\|X\|_k \lesssim \begin{cases}
\sqrt{n p k} & \text{if $\beta < e$} \\
\frac{k}{\log\beta} & \text{if $\beta\ge e$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Putting it all together we have

$$
E\left[\left(\frac{X}{np}\right)^k\right] \le \begin{cases}
(1 + C\sqrt{\frac{k}{np}})^k & \text{if $\beta < e$} \\
(1 + C\frac{k}{n p\log\beta})^k & \text{if $\beta\ge e$}.
\end{cases}
$$

In particular for $k = O((n p)^{1/3})$ we get $E(\frac{X}{np})^k=1 + O(k^3/(n p))$.
This is not quite as good as the conjectured bound, but at least it is rigorous and works even when $p$ is also allowed to depend on $n$.

It also shows that the moments of $\frac{X}{np}-1$ are within a constant of the equivalent Gaussian, as long as $k < np$.

Likely one has to avoid the triangle inequality to show the stronger conjecture.

Comment: Note that "bounding by normal variables" work for *symmetric* binomials.
I think this case requires more work.

Comment: @MaciejS. It turns out that "mean zero" and "symmetric" are equivalent in terms of norms up to a constant factor. This is called "symmetrization" on the notes.

Comment: Yes, but symmetric binomials give Rademachers even without symmetrization, while your $B_i-C_i$ are not rademachers so Kchintchine's inequality cannot be directly applied. $B_i-C_i$ takes 3 values including zero (!) so some further majorization is needed

Comment: @MaciejS. You are right. I have rewritten the proof avoiding Kchintchine.

Answer (score 4):

The $k$th moment of a Binomial$(n,p)$ random variable $X$ is 
$$\mathbb{E}(X^k)=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}j!{n\choose j}p^j,\tag1$$
where ${k\brace j}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

For large $n$, we have $j!{n\choose j}\approx n^j-{j\choose 2}n^{j-1}$.
Taking the two leading terms in (1)  gives the approximation
$$\mathbb{E}(X^k)\approx \left[n^k-{k\choose 2}n^{k-1}\right]p^k+{k\choose 2}n^{k-1}p^{k-1}=(np)^k+{k\choose 2}(np)^{k-1}(1-p),$$
since ${k\brace k}=1$ and ${k\brace k-1}={k\choose 2}.$

Comment: Great! Is it obvious that the lower order terms don't sum up and become too large?

Comment: @ThomasAhle All the remaining terms have powers of $n$ less than or equal to $k-2$.

Comment: Right, what if we allow $k$ to grow with $n$? $k=\sqrt{n}$ seems like it would cause trouble. Can we say something about how fast it's allowed to grow?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Hmmm, that's a different question. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: No problem. $j!{n\choose j}\approx n^j-{j\choose 2}n^{j-1}$, does that follow from Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Not Stirling's formula, rather finding the large powers of $n$ in $j!{n\choose j}=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-j+1).$

Comment: Does anybody have a reference (a book is better) for the formula above using Stirling numbers?