# Bound on the kth moment of the mean of X

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have $X_1, X_2,..., X_h$ independent random variables with the distribution  $P(X_m=1)=P$ and $P(X_m=0)=1-P$.

We put $X=X_1+...+X_h$ so that X is a random variable with expectation $hP.$

Here is my question:
If $hP \geq 1$, why do we have

$\mathbb{E}(( X-hP)^k) \ll_k  (hP)^{k/2}.$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853187

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asymptotic Moments of the Binomial Distribution, $E(X/(np))^k = 1 + O(k^2/n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853187/asymptotic-moments-of-the-binomial-distribution-ex-npk-1-ok2-n)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a route:

$\quad(1)$: Show that $X\sim \text{Binomial}(h,p)$.

$\quad(2)$: Show that if $M_X(t)$ is the [mgf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$ and $W=U+V$, then $M_W(t)=M_U(t)+M_V(t)$.

$\quad(3)$: Show that the mgf of a $\text{Binomial}(h,p)$ is $(1-p+pe^t)^h$.

$\quad(4)$: Calculate the mgf of a constant random variable and obtain the mgf of $Y=X-hp$.

$\quad(5)$: Show that for a constant $c$, $\text{Var}(X+c)=\text{Var}(X)$, and hence $\sigma(X+c)=\sigma(X)$.

$\quad(6)$: Relate the inequality to the expression

$$\frac{m_k(Y)}{\sigma(Y)},$$

where $m_k(Y)$ is the $k$-th moment of $Y$.