# Binomial Sum with Power of index

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I need to find either the exact solution or a tight lower bound for the following sum:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k y^{n-k} k^m$

For $m=0$ the solution is the Binomial Theorem $(x+y)^n$. The case for $m=1$ can be obtained by differentiation on $x$ which gives $nx(x+y)^{n-1}$. If I do this iteratively it starts getting troublesome and I don't know how to generalize the formula for the $m$th case.

Originally I got this sum for the case where $x = 1 - y$ and $x,y \in [0,1]$. But I think that the general case should have a known formula.

Comment: Take $x = e^t$.  Then your expression is

$$\dfrac{d^m}{dt^m} (e^t+y)^n $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${n \brace k}$ denote the $(n,k)^{th}$ Stirling number of the second kind. Using the well-known identity
$$
k^m=\sum_{j=0}^m {m \brace j}\frac{k!}{(k-j)!},
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k k^m x^k y^{n-k}
  &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k x^k y^{n-k}\sum_{j=1}^m {m\brace j}\frac{k!}{(k-j)!}
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^m\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}{m \brace j}\sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n-j}{k-j}x^ky^{n-k}
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{n!}{(n-j)!}{m \brace j}x^j(x+y)^{n-j} 
\end{align}
$$
In the special case where $y=1-x$ that you mentioned, this simplifies a bit more to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{n!}{(n-j)!}{m \brace j}x^j
$$
In this special case, the summation is also equal to the $m^{th}$ binomial moment. That is, it is the expected value of $X^m$ when $X$ has the $\text{Binomial}(n,x)$ distribution. There's some more info about these moments on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Higher_moments), including an upper bound, but no lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. Given the answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853187/asymptotic-moments-of-the-binomial-distribution-ex-npk-1-ok2-n/2581762#2581762) and yours I got a close answer to my question.